# How to execute a class method by string input in C++

Tags: c++, string, input, methods

I am trying to develop a text adventure in C++ where users can input string commands (ex. "take apple").
Here is a very naive sample of code I came up with:

```
# include <iostream>     
using namespace std;

class fruit{
    public:
        string actual_name;
        fruit(string name){
            actual_name = name;
        }
        take() {
            cout << "You take a " << actual_name << "." << endl;
        }
};

fruit returnObjectFromName(string name, fruit Fruits[]){
    for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++){  // to be modified in future depending on Fruits[] in main()
        if (Fruits[i].actual_name == name)
            return Fruits[i];
        }
}

int main(){
    string verb;
    cout << "Enter verb: ";
    cin >> verb;
    string object;
    cout << "Enter object: ";
    cin >> object;
    fruit apple("apple");
    fruit Fruits[] = { apple }; // to be extended in future
    // returnObjectFromName(object, Fruits). ??? ()
}
```

How can I possibly get the fruit method with something similar to the function returnObjectFromName, if this is even possible?
I began the development with Python (independently), and there I can at least use eval(), but as I understand in C++ this is not an option.
I tried also with map, but I didn't manage to make it work with methods.

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: You may be looking for [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Comment: Wait... I'm probably reading this wrong. `returnObjectFromName(object, Fruits).my_fruit_method();` should work. If it's not working for you, please expand your problem description with a code example showing exactly what you have tried so we can show you how to correct it.

Comment: Side note: `returnObjectFromName` will fail to reach a return statement if `name` cannot be matched. This is fatal for a program. When a function promises to return a value, it must return a value in every case.

Comment: Side note:a `<=` in a for loop exit condition is a bug more often than not. eg: note the possible values of `i` in `for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)`. First iteration `i` is 0. 0 <= 1, so the loop enters. `i++` increases `i` to 1. 1 <= 1, so the loop enters. Unfortunately there is no `Fruits[1]` so the program fails. Maybe it fails loudly and crashes or spits out nonsense. Maybe it fails so quietly that you don't notice right away. Maybe you don't notice for weeks. Maybe you don't notice until you show the program off to your boss, or at a trade show, or the autonomous car didn't hit the brakes.

Comment: user4581301 about your side notes: you're absolutely right. But now I'm just testing if everything works fine when inputs are correct. "returnObjectFromName(object, Fruits).my_fruit_method(); should work" that's exactly what I tried to achieve, but my_fruit_method comes as a string and I couldn't create a function like, for example, returnMethodFromVerb(). That would be possible if I could pass through all class methods, but as I understand that is impossible.

Comment: In C and C++ you can't create a method on the fly. The closest you can do is have a map of terms to existing functions. `std::map<std::string, std::function<void ()>>verbs = { { "take", take_function }, { "eat", eat_function } };`. Then you can `verb.at(user_action)();` to call the function for the string in `user_action`. `at` will throw an exception if `user_action` does not contain a known string.

Comment: Side note: If you use the `[]` operator instead of `at`, `map` will create a new `std::function` that doesn't represent any function, stuff it into the `map`, and try to call it with the kind of bad result you should expect from calling a function that doesn't exist. [Documentation for `std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: lol, in c++ don't exist `eval()` like functional, it's mb implemented multiple ways. But I think save `&Type::method` ptr with assigned string "name" the most simple way for u.

Answer (score 0):

Its not good way to rely on reflection in C++ and i think there is no way to list methods in classes. Maybe you can use function pointers but pointer to instance methods are hell.

I recommend to use polymorphism and good design. If some items might be taken, then use interface like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ITakeable {
    public:
        virtual bool isTakeable() = 0;
        virtual void take() = 0;
        virtual void cannotTake() = 0;
};

class fruit : public ITakeable {
    public:
        string actual_name;
        
        fruit(string name){
            actual_name = name;
        }
        
        bool isTakeable() {
            return true;
        }
        
        void take() {
            cout << "You take a " << actual_name << "." << endl;
        }
        
        void cannotTake() {
            cout << "not needed to be implemented";
        }
};

class airplane : public ITakeable {
    public:
        string actual_name;
        
        airplane(string name){
            actual_name = name;
        }
        
        bool isTakeable() {
            return false;
        }
        
        void take() {
            cout << "not needed to be implemented";
        }
        
        void cannotTake() {
            cout << "You CANNOT take a " << actual_name << "." << endl;
        }
};


int main() {
   fruit apple("apple");
   
   if (apple.isTakeable()) {
       apple.take();
   }
   
   airplane plane("boeing");

   if (plane.isTakeable()) {
       plane.take();
   } else {
       plane.cannotTake();
   }
   
   // use of interface in general
   
   ITakeable * something = &apple;

   if (something->isTakeable()) {
       something->take();
   }
   
   something = &plane;

   if (something->isTakeable()) {
       something->take();
   } else {
       something->cannotTake();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pointers to member [is indeed hellish](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members), but 2011's  C++ Standard revision (AKA C++11) added [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to clean up the mess. It does a pretty good job. Combine it with [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=msvc-160)  and it's pretty easy.

Answer (score -2):

Since fruit is a user defined type, you have to declare your own methods for your type or you inherit from one previously defined.

There are a lot of method for "built-in" string type
that Performs virtually the same job as eval (...) in python.

Also I noticed your function need not be defined independently outside of class fruit.